# Passing data from one screen to another screen with react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm currently passing the data to one component in `react-native` with some code which is shown as below:

```
class Login extends Component {
  signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await Google.logInAsync({
        iosClientId: IOS_CLIENT_ID,
        androidClientId: ANDROID_CLIENT_ID,
        scopes: ["profile", "email"]
      });

      if (result.type === "success") {
        console.log(
          "LoginScreen.js.js 21 | ",
          result.user.givenName,
          result.user.familyName,
          result.user.email,
          result.user.photoUrl
        );
        this.props.navigation.navigate(
          "MyDrawer",
          (username = result.user.givenName),
          (lastname = result.user.familyName),
          (email = result.user.email),
          (photoUrl = result.user.photoUrl)
        );
        return result.accessToken;
      } else {
        return { cancelled: true };
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("LoginScreen.js.js 30 | Error with login", e);
      return { error: true };
    }
  };
}
```

My question is **how do I pass the data to a different component**?

Comment: What *is* the data and *where* is it being passed to any component? Please include a [Minimal and Complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your code and where your issue is.

Comment: The data is fetched from google's API. It gets the name, family name, email and photoURI. The snippet that passes the data is named _dataPassing.js_ in [this gist snippet](https://gist.github.com/MislavPeric/9e24cdde4cd061d4c8fd3477161d556f).
Then I use the data in _Drawer.js_, I'd like, somehow, to pass that same data to _QR.js_
The code for all 3 files and the small snippet inside _Login.js_ that takes the role of data passing is in the gist

Comment: Ah, I see, it seems you are at least passing it via a navigation action to some component, and you are asking how to pass it to another? What is the relationship between the current component, the one being navigated to, and this *third* component?

Comment: The _Login.js_ calls the _MyDrawer.js_ via StackNavigation at the bottom. When you press the button and the login completes, the function sends you to _MyDrawer.js_, which renders the DrawerNavigation which contains the 3rd component _QR.js_ (You can see this drawer navigation at the bottom of the _Drawer.js_ file)

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass an object as second parameter to the navigate method that is in props.
to pass a data to a different component, provide an object as the second argument for the navigate function

change this

```
 this.props.navigation.navigate(
          "MyDrawer",
          (username = result.user.givenName),
          (lastname = result.user.familyName),
          (email = result.user.email),
          (photoUrl = result.user.photoUrl)
        );
```

to

```
 this.props.navigation.navigate("MyDrawer",{
  name: result.user.givenName,
  lastname : result.user.familyName,
  email :result.user.email,
  photoUrl = result.user.photoUrl
});
```

now in the component that you are passing the data to, you can get the keys using the getKey method of react-navigation

TargetComponent.js

```
render() {
    email = this.props.navigation.getParam("email", defaultValue);
  password= this.props.navigation.getParam("password", defaultValue);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm using React Navigation 5 and Hooks. Both the _Drawer.js_ and _QR.js_ (the targeted component) are Functions, not Classes.

Comment: You have access to navigation regardless via useNavigation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/

Comment: Doing it [this way](https://gist.github.com/MislavPeric/c1496e852a99e5c438bcb803548b1e11) Throws me an error
_invariant violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component._